# A question about $\delta(x) \star \delta(p)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, phase-space, dirac-delta-distributions, deformation-quantization

Using the Moyal product between two delta functions in $(x,p)$-space one gets
$$ \delta(x) \star \delta(p) = \frac{1}{\pi} e^{2ixp}. $$

However, $\delta(-x)=\delta(x)$ and last time I checked $e^{2ixp} \neq e^{-2ixp}$.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the star operator also depends on *x*,
$$ \delta (x) ~ \star ~ \delta(p) =  \delta (x) ~   \exp{\left( \frac{i \hbar}{2} \left(\overleftarrow {\partial }_x
\overrightarrow{\partial }_p-\overleftarrow{\partial }_p \overrightarrow {\partial }_x \right) \right)}  ~ \delta(p)   ={2\over h} 
\exp \left (2i{xp\over\hbar}\right ). 
$$
Consequently, flipping the sign of *x* complex conjugates it, even though it leaves the delta function invariant.

Comment: Ah, of course, thanks!